# MySQL get only the row with the highest ID of a query

Tags: mysql

Hello Stackoverflow community,

This is my first post here, so I apologize for my bad English! :)

If you don't want to read everything, the Questions are marked **like this**.

The title is a little misleading, but I didn't know how to explain it in a better way, but the detailed explanation should let you understand:

I have a big log table (about 500000 rows at this time), where a game server logs many actions that occur in the game. I want to extract some specific log rows the most efficient way.

I can't change the logging system of the game server, if I could I would change it to many more log tables, to create more compact logs. (because executing queries on that table takes it's time..)

Now my problem is, that I want to get the last log row of a specific type and from a specific player id to get the players last action, and I don't know how to do that in an efficient way.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE logType = "PLAYER" AND playerID = [playerID] ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Then the output on the website would be:
You last action was [the human readable action and additional information].

MySQL profiling now tells me that sorting of the results takes the most amount of time.

Now my question is: **Is it possible to get only the last row of a specific player id and type?**
I guess it could be done with the ID, cause it has auto_increment. So **is it possible to get the row with the highest ID, a specific type and a specific player id?**

The table structure:
ID(int) | logType(varchar) | time(datetime) | playerID(int) | positionX(int) | positionY(int) | actionID(int) | action(varchar) | hints(varchar) | ip(varchar) | itemNumber(int)

Explaination:

ID: the unique id of the logged action

logType: the type of the logged action (Example: "PLAYER" or "ITEM")

time: the time the action occured

playerID: the id of the player (or other id's related to that type)

positionX: X position in the game

positionY: Y position in the game

actionID: an id in relation to the action (Example: If the log action is "KILLED_BY_PLAYER", then the player id of the other player who killed the player)

action: the action that is logged (Example: KILLED_BY_PLAYER)

hints: Some useful hints like the name of the player

ip: The IP of the player

itemNumber: The number of the Item, if an Item is involved, else NULL

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: If the table is ordered by auto-increment ID, then you should just be able to order by ID desc, limit 1.

Comment: This is a little bit faster than sorting with time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to get the highest id:

```
select max(id) from table;
```

the others you could put a where clause in the select statement.

Comment: This gets the right `ID`, but unfortunately the other fields aren't from the row with that ID. But it works quite faster if I use 2 queries, so thanks! Edit: What I mean with 2 queries: `SELECT * FROM log WHERE ID=(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM log WHERE logType = "PLAYER" AND playerID = [playerID]);`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use your query where you sort on `time` with `LIMIT 1`. If your sort on the column `time` is slow, you must make sure the indexes are optimized (run `explain` on your query). You will need indexes on both `logtype`, `player_id` and `time`. Even with 500 000 rows this shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: It's not a real problem, it only takes like 1 to 5 seconds. But I wanted to know if I could skip the sorting. I thought of something like getting **only** the row with the highest ID which matches the specific things like `logType` and `playerID`. But it's okay if it isn't possible without sorting. :)

Comment: well, you do need to sort either by `SORT` or by `MAX`. Either way, I would expect the query to execute in much less than a second. When I run a similar query in one of my tables with 1.6 million rows, it executes in 4.1 ms... If the execution time is 1-5 seconds, something must be wrong! Maybe you can post the output of an `EXPLAIN` on your query?

Comment: `1 | SIMPLE | log | index | playerID,logType | time | 9 | NULL | 2 | Using where`
That's the output using the query `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM log WHERE logType = "PLAYER" AND playerID = 1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1`, I hope you can read it cause I'm not able to put the headline correctly in this comment :/

Comment: it's difficult to read the output, but it seems the key that is being used is `time` but that there is no index on it (`NULL`)?

Comment: I double-checked and time has an index according to PHPMyAdmin.. I think I'll have to go through the MySQL Config to optimize it, because I never cared much about that. Thank you for your help! :)